# How do I share my Ditto clipboard with multiple machines on my network?

Tags: clipboard, ditto

I'm using [Ditto Clipboard Manager](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) and wish to share the clipboard on multiple machines on my home network. I've heard that you can do this but haven't found any help on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know... you might be able to do it with DropBox.

1. Install DropBox and set up an account.  You get 2 GB for free.
2. Change Ditto Database Path (in Options) to your Shared DropBox folder
3. That will now be available to all other computers in which you have your DropBox running.

Comment: I was unable to sync the db since DropBox couldn't sync the file because Ditto have it open.

Comment: I used Google Drive and it works fine.  Might need to restart Ditto after making the changes.  It works over the internet as long as the changes sync properly.

Comment: This hits the internet (with encryption) and uses a third-party solution, even though Ditto natively supports sharing your clips over a LAN. There is also the possibility of a DropBox sync conflict if you copy a file to the clipboard on both machines simultaneously.

Comment: Ditto has a sharing feature for LAN. All you need is two computers running ditto. As long as both computer have the other marked as "Friend" and both know a specific secret password it should all go fine without 3th party cloud services

Answer (score 5):

Yes you must be running Ditto on every machine, that you want to share on the network.

- Right click on the Ditto ball & select Options
- go to the Friends tab & put ALL names you wish to share or use their IP's; separate each one with a semicolon.
- go down to the bottom & insert each one of the machines into the Send All to; make sure there is an X in Send All.
- Once that is done go to the Exporting machine; Bring up the Ditto Window, however you wish; either by Left clicking on Ditto Ball or using Hot Keys.
- Then use Control CTL + A to select All clips on your clipboard;
- then right click on anywhere on the Ditto Pop-Up Window & use the *Send To* Option in the Pop-Up Menu. There you have it Sent All Clips To Network Machine.

Comment: I made an error.  You DO NOT have to use Control CTL + A; when you have the Select All Clips X marked in the Friend tab.  It does the CTL + A for you.

Comment: Once you do this on all machines you want sharing clipboard data, Ditto will automatically synchronize them for you from then on. You'll want to make sure Ditto is on your firewall exceptions list for Private networks.

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the list (Ctrl + ' or whatever). Right click and export. Save file and transfer to other machine. You can then import by right clicking on the notification icon.

As for syncing automatically, there is the friends tab in options but I don't really think it helps. You can specify the database location though, so maybe setting that as the same network location for all machines could work?

Comment: This shares specific clips, not the clipboard as a whole. The Friends tab is the ideal method for syncing Ditto between computers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what David said, or you can install the portable version, and create links in the startup folder to run the same version on both machines. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to be running Ditto on both machines.

Comment: Done that. Now how do I sync the DB's or refer to the same DB?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do it is to copy the db from one computer to another. navigate to /users/your name/appdata/roaming/ditto/ditto.db and copy "ditto.db"

the path may be different dependinbg on your OS, but the point is you can copy the database, including whatever hot keys you have programed.

reverse the process on the other computer & paste it.

I understand you can make the computers to sync ditto if they are on the same network, but I have not been able to get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by sharing the folder where the database file is on the local network, the pointing the database to the correct location in Ditto's settings. It's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the database location to a folder on my synced google drive, and did the same on several other machines. It works most of the time, but sometimes the sync on google drive crashes into the ditto app and corrupts the database. Make sure you keep a backup.